# Select where in() for each id return equal rows count

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

How to select rows for each `user_id` equals select numbers of count for each `user_id`?

My example table:

```
mp3_id  |  user_id
--------------------
120     |  840
123     |  840
126     |  840
128     |  455
130     |  840
131     |  840
132     |  840
135     |  840
144     |  840
158     |  840
159     |  455
161     |  455
169     |  455
180     |  840
181     |  455
184     |  455
186     |  455
189     |  455
```

My simple query:

`select mp3_id where user_id IN (840,455) limit 8`

Return:

```
mp3_id  |  user_id
--------------------
120     |  840
123     |  840
126     |  840
128     |  455
130     |  840
131     |  840
132     |  840
135     |  840
```

But I want to this select:

```
mp3_id  |  user_id
--------------------
120     |  840
123     |  840
126     |  840
130     |  840
128     |  455
159     |  455
161     |  455
169     |  455
```

I want each `user_id` to return an equal row count. How to?

Comment: I see this is just an example. You do know that you are picking arbitrary records, because of using `limit` without an `order by` clause, right?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, but this example is part of my nested query. without union how to best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   AND y.mp3_id <= x.mp3_id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.mp3_id HAVING COUNT(*) <= 4 
 ORDER  
    BY user_id DESC
     , mp3_id;
```

or faster

```
SELECT mp3_id, user_id FROM
 (
 SELECT x.*, CASE WHEN @prev = user_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i, @prev:=user_id FROM my_table x, (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=1) vars ORDER BY user_id DESC, mp3_id
 ) a
 WHERE i<=4;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a UNION:

```
select mp3_id where user_id = 840 limit 4
union all
select mp3_id where user_id = 455 limit 4
```

Comment: yes i know. but count ids in IN() is Unknown. 840,455,1450

Comment: How can this be unknown? How do you get the IDs in the `IN` clause? If you put can put any number of IDs in the `IN` clause, you should also be able to write as many queries.

Comment: yes count of ids is defined. but nit fix. 2, 3,4,5,or 1.

Comment: What is so bad about this solution? I see no disadvantage. You'd union two queries for two IDs, three for three, etc.

Comment: An alternative could be to apply row numbers (which is done with variables in MySQL) per ID and then use `where ID in (840,455,1450) and rownum <= 4`. But this would be more complicated and I don't see the advantage in that.

Comment: for each select union i use by string builder for dynamic ids?

Comment: Well, you loop over IDs adding one query for each ID. You tagged mysqli, which is PHP if I am not mistaken. And I think PHP has no stringbuilder. Anyway, whatever language, it's a loop that adds query strings.

Answer (score 2):

try this query:

```
select
yt.mp3_id,
e.user_id
from
(
    select distinct user_id from your_table
) e
join your_table yt on true
where yt.mp3_id in (select tt.mp3_id from your_table tt where tt.user_id = e.user_id order by tt.mp3_id limit 4)
```

and tihs same query but with condition

```
select
yt.mp3_id,
e.user_id
from
(
    select distinct user_id from your_table where user_id in (840,455)
) e
join your_table yt on true
where yt.mp3_id in (select tt.mp3_id from your_table tt where tt.user_id = e.user_id order by tt.mp3_id limit 4)
```

Comment: @Abihabi87: That's a smart idea.

Comment: Abihabi87, where is `where user_id IN()` ?

Comment: @grizzly - it works for all user_id but if you want olny a few you can add `where user_id in (840,455)` in nested query

Comment: `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`